# PostgreSQL - query behaves inconsistently - what is causing this?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I have a query in PostgreSQL (rather a func call) which returns normally for say 5-6 secs. This happens in 90-59% of the cases, I think. Sometimes though this same func call takes 10-20 mins or even 1-2 hours. The parameters passed to the func in this "slower case" are the same as in the "faster case".

What could be causing this? Is it possible that the PostgreSQL picks a different execution plan even though the parameters are exactly the same?

Since I will be asked about the overall server load... I don't think it's related. I believe I have seen cases where my func call is slow even without any significant additional load on the server (by other client sessions).

So when would the query be slow seems completely random to me. But logically speaking, I know it cannot be random, it should be influenced by some factor.

That's exactly my point here: what is this factor? This seems a deep issue so any good suggestions or hints would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge Not really... It is a func call and there are multiple queries involved. But the slowness is always in the final SELECT of the func. The thing is ... it is not always slow... Same query with same params is sometimes fast and sometimes (more rarely) it is slow. So even if I share the query I am not sure it will provide any valuable information. Not to talk that one needs to be familiar  with the tables involved etc.

Comment: Parameter sniffing - are there any other function calls   between yours with broader/wider range for instance dates?

Comment: @peter.petrov That SELECT will always join / filter / order by the same columns regardless of the parameters?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda What do you mean between my calls? We already did param sniffing, the params (for the func call in question) are known.

Comment: I meant you run your query with param (10,10) then another session/user calls(1,1) and you try (10,10) once again. So from your perspective you are running the same calls every time.

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge No, it will filter and order on different things but they depend on the param values. As I said inconsistent behavior happens even for the same param values.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That is a possible scenario, yes. To have multiple calls (at the same time) with different parameter values.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda But sometimes I have seen the func call gets slow even if we keep calling it with the same params only (say we call it 4 times repeatedly, the first 3 runs are OK/fast, the last one gets slow and takes way more time). This is the typical thing I have seen.

Comment: Maybe some buffer page flushing/blocking.  Could you grab the execution plans for both fast/slow runs?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I can try and post later here. It's not easy because it's not a consistent behavior as I mentioned. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. If you can suggest some other tricks :) based on the information so far - please do, much appreciated.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda For now all I need are a few good ideas/hints and I will dig in further. I've been struggling with this issue for the past 3-4 days so... I am not expecting to have it solved in 1-2 hours.

Comment: I do not know AWS but I assume there should be some performance monitoring tools/query store/tuning advisor that would help you to intercept slowest/degrading queries.

Comment: @peter.petrov Can you use auto_explain module to try to figure out if it does choose different execution plans?

Comment: @peter.petrov Could it also be cache related? Can you try to execute the query with parameters that have never been used to see if it runs fast or slow for the first time?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge We tried using this auto_explain yesterday but I don't think we came up with anything conclusive. Not sure.

Comment: Isolate PostrgeSql environment and test there. If this is a production server you cannot be sure what exactly is happening. The database will take different plans depending on the available resources and so you can guess that will happen if there is not enough memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `ANALYZE "tbl"` statements for **all temp tables** used in my function after inserting the data into them. I also added a few indexes to some of the largest temp tables.

This seems to have fixed the issue. I guess I will never know what exactly the issue was, but it seems to me Postgres was picking a different execution plan even for the same func arguments.

Now when I explicitly say: "go and analyze these temp tables", it seems Postgres is picking always the same/fast execution plan/path.

Just posting this answer here so that others may try it too, if they run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, postgres can pick a different execution plan, which may be the cause of the issue, but that seems unlikely to me.

Have you looked at pg_stat_activity while the query is running for a long time?  Check to see that it is not stuck waiting on some other process that has obtained a lock.

Comment: No, blocking was not the cause. I checked blockings, there were none. I just forgot to mention it here that I checked blockings already.